# Is There a Facebook Visual Studio vsdoc?

Tags: facebook, vsdoc

So I've been using the jQuery Visual Studio vsdoc for awhile now to provide intellisense support. Does anyone know if there is a vsdoc for the Facebook Javascript SDK?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is not one at this time.